# How to handle input box inside iframe without id or name

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, iframe

how to handle input box inside iframe like this?
[iframe][1]

```
Dim driver As New WebDriver

On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
driver.Start "chrome"
driver.Get "https://www201.ynspire.net:8443/sso/XUI/#login/&metaAlias=/sp&idpEntityID=https://www401.ynspire.net:8443/sso&reqBinding=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST&goto=http%3A%2F%2Fwww203.ynspire.net%3A8000%2Feproc_ypmi"
driver.Window.Maximize

driver.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 5000          ' 5 seconds driver.Timeouts.PageLoad = 10000

driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/fieldset/div[1]/input").SendKeys (xn)
driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/fieldset/div[2]/input").SendKeys (ps)
driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/fieldset/div[3]/input").Click

driver.SwitchToFrame (0)

driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div").Click
driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[3]/div").Click

Sleep 2000

driver.SwitchToFrame driver.FindElementByCss("iframe[src^='/eproc_ypmi/ic/ic04/Ic0401.do']")

driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[3]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/input").SendKeys (Workbooks(ini).Worksheets("RPA RN").Range("H1").Value)
driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[3]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/input").Click
```

Comment: Please check I have formatted your code accurately. We also need more detail on the problem such as what is currently happening/not happening and any error codes. You appear to have tried to add an image. You can use [edit] and the edit toolbar to insert html which is preferable to images of code.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` in case of masked errors